# How to pass data between tasks in Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Im newbie of SCDF and I have a question when using composed-tasks

SCDF provides DSL to create composed-tasks consists of more than one tasks.
Then I want to know how can I pass data between tasks in composed-tasks

For example, when I created composed tasks with `timestamp && print`.
`timestamp` task get current timestamp and `print` task recieve time information with parameter and print it to console.
Then I have to pass `timestamp` value to `print` tasks.
Does SCDF support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can pass application/deployer properties for child tasks inside a composed task. You can refer the SCDF documentation for the same [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_properties_to_the_child_tasks)

Comment: Thanks for answer, then can I put results of sub-tasks in to application/deployer properties? I usually use it to pass kubernetes options, or job parameters. I thought it could be set only before start composed-tasks.

Comment: At this time there is no way to do this via composed tasks unless you write the supporting code in your tasks.   Can you do me a favor and add this as a github issue here:  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues .   Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the original question. Thanks for the clarification Glenn! I went ahead and created issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/4046

Comment: @GlennRenfro is there an example how to do that using "supporting code in the task". So for example there is some rest request response in the task (code) and I want next one to be able to use it inside the code? 
Should I put it to the database manually and pick it up within next task?